# JSON RPC - Error when getting the response : RpcAuthenticationException

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a JSON RPC API to get data.

Here is the error I get:

```json
{{
  "id": 0,
  "error": {
    "trace": "RpcAuthenticationException",
    "code": 490
  }
}}
```

Here is the main class of my code which implements normally the call to the API:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.1.10/api/jsonrpc");
webRequest.Headers.Set("Csrf_token", "***");
webRequest.Headers.Set("Cookie", "****");
webRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "default");

webRequest.ContentType = "application/json-rpc";
webRequest.Method = "POST";

JObject joe = new JObject();
//joe["jsonrpc"] = "1.0";
joe["id"] = 0;
joe["method"] = "***";
joe["params"] = "[]";


string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe);
// serialize json for the request
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

try
{
    using (Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    //inner exception is socket
    //{"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 23.23.246.5:8332"}
    throw;
}
WebResponse webResponse = null;
try
{
    using (webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream str = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str))
            {

                var tempRet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                                      Console.Write(tempRet);

            }
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException webex)
{

    using (Stream str = webex.Response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str))
        {
            var tempRet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            Console.Write(tempRet);
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

Does someone have a solution? I have made a lot of test with a lot of different code and every time I get this answer so if you have an idea I will be happy.

Comment: You need to check how the server wants the authentication. You are currently using Basic along with some kind of Cookie, but we don't know if that's what the server is expecting. Side notes: so much badness here. Don't use `HttpWebRequest`, it's deprecated, use `HttpClient` instead. `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is just blindly trusting the server certificate, it would make more sense to get a proper cert, or not bother with encryption at all. You should be specifying the `jsonrpc` version number (the commented out line), which should be 2.0, unless the server is really old.